# Can execute a program with my IDE but not by doubleclicking when a module is imported

Tags: python, module

I've tried to execute two scripts, one with a module imported and one without.

I doubleclicked the one with the module and a window appeared and disappeared quickly, then I tried the other one without and it worked.

Can someone help me figure it out? Thanks.

Precisions: I've tried other scripts with other modules but it doesn't work, both scripts don't have any errors.
I'm on windows 10 and both scripts are to print the prime factors of a given number, one with the math module and the other without.
I can still execute the one with the module with my IDE but I'd prefer not to open my IDE to execute scripts with modules.

If you want the scripts:

```
# The one without the module ik it's not optimized
num = 56475871
nvNum = 2
nbsPmrs = []
res = []

for nvNum in range(num):
    if not nvNum % 2 == 0 and not nvNum % 3 == 0 and not nvNum % 5 == 0 and not nvNum == 1 or nvNum == 2 or nvNum == 3 or nvNum == 5:
        nbsPmrs.append(nvNum)

for a in range(1, len(nbsPmrs), 1):
    if num % nbsPmrs[a] == 0:
        res.append(nbsPmrs[a])

print(res)
# -----------------------------------------------------
# The one with the module

from math import *

num = 56475871
res = []
t = int(sqrt(num))
for i in range(t):
    while num % 2 == 0:
        num //= 2
        res.append(2)
        if num % 2 != 0:
            break
for a in range(3, t, 1):
    if num % a == 0:
        num //= a
        res.append(a)

res.append(num)
print(res)
```

Comment: There’s too little detail to help you. Could you make a very small program with the same behaviour, and post it here. Also, please specify operating system.

Comment: @Stefan I'm on windows and basically it's printing the prime factors of a number, the module used is math to calculate the square root of a number

Comment: Could you provide the code? I reckon this is a simple case of stout showing when run from the IDE or command line, which doesn't happen when double clicking the file from Windows

Comment: @LouieC I edited the original so there's the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, this is a case of the result printing and the window closing as the script is complete; nothing to do with the import

To keep the window open, you can simply add the following line to the end of the script

```
input('Press Enter to quit')
```

You're also missing your final print statement on the second script; hence no output

I got this to work as expected:

```
from math import *

num = 56475871
res = []
t = int(sqrt(num))
for i in range(t):
    while num % 2 == 0:
        num //= 2
        res.append(2)
        if num % 2 != 0:
            break
for a in range(3, t, 1):
    if num % a == 0:
        num //= a
        res.append(a)

res.append(num)
print(res)
input('Press Enter to quit')
```

Comment: ;-; I did what you said and I kinda feel dumb, thanks for the answer!